# re-use the androidmanifest.xml in library project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am buiding an android application with two version one for free and the other for paid.

Since most of the UI,feature of the two version are the same, so I create a Android library project to hold the common components of the app including the common `Activity`, `View` , `Layout` , `Resources` and the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The library project is named `MapBase`.

Then I create two moudles(android application) named `MapForFree` and `MapForPaid`.

The structure:

```
+MapProject

  +MapBase
    build.gradle
  +MapForFree
    build.gradle
  +MapForPaid
    build.gradle

  build.gradle(with empty content)
  settings.gradle(content==> include ':MapBase', ':MapForFree', ':MapForPaid')
```

The MapBase/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
.....
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

MapForFee/build.gradle:

```
...
apply plugin: 'android'
...
```

Now I want to the `MapForFree` and `MapForPaid` to refer to the `MapBase` module, but I meet two problems:

1 The refer manner.

Should I set the dependency in the build.gradle file or using android stuido itself?

2 The AndroidManifest.xml.

Since the `MapForFree` and `MapForPaid` module have the same AndroidManifest.xml, so I copy this file from `MapBase`.

However, the file declare some Activities defined in the `MapBase` module. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your first question. For your second question, `MapForFree` and `MapForPaid` should each have their own `AndroidManifest.xml`. Any components that need to be defined in the manifest that come from `MapBase` should be defined using the full package name of `MapBase` before the component name.

For example, if you have an `Activity` defined in `MapBase` called `MapBaseActivity`, and it is in package `com.example.app`, it should be listed in the manifests for both `MapForFree` and `MapForPaid` as:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.MapBaseActivity">
```